# Reading large volume data from Teradata using Dask cluster/Teradatasql and sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed, teradatasql

I need to read large volume data(app. 800M records) from teradata, my code is working fine for a million record. for larger sets its taking time to build metadata. Could someone please suggest how to make it faster. Below is the code snippet which I am using for my application.

```
def get_partitions(num_partitions):
    list_range =[]
    initial_start=0
    for i in range(num_partitions):
        amp_range = 3240//num_partitions
        start = (i*amp_range+1)*initial_start
        end   = (i+1)*amp_range
        list_range.append((start,end))
        initial_start = 1
    return list_range

@delayed
def load(query,start,end,connString):
    df = pd.read_sql(query.format(start, end),connString)
    engine.dispose()
    return df

connString = "teradatasql://{user}:{password}@{hostname}/?logmech={logmech}&encryptdata=true"

results = from_delayed([load(query,start, end,connString) for start,end in get_partitions(num_partitions)])
```

Answer (score 0):

The build time is probably taken in finding out the metadata of your table. This is done by fetching the *whole* of the first partition and analysing it.

You would be better off either specifying it explcitly, if you know the dtypes upfront, e.g., `{col: dtype, ...}` for all the columns, or generating it from a separate query that you limit to just as many rows as it takes to be sure you have the right types:

```
meta = dask.compute(load(query, 0,10 ,connString))

results = from_delayed(
    [
        load(query,start, end,connString) for start,end in 
        get_partitions(num_partitions)
    ],
    mete=meta.loc[:0, :]  # zero-length version of table
)
```